# Realizar llamadas Ajax dentro de un loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

Debo realizar llamadas Ajax con parámetros dinámicos, utilizo el $.each para recorrer los valores de los parámetros y mandarlos a la llamada ajax pero al parecer se ejecutan al mismo tiempo, y deseo que se ejecute una después de otra, como es dinámico no tengo un número exacto de llamadas a Ajax, alguna idea?? Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
 $.each(params, function (index, value) {
                v1 = value.v1;
                v2 = value.v2;

                llamadoAjax(v1, v2);
            });
```

Donde llamadoAjax es:

```
var parametros = {
    v1: v1,
    v2: v2
}

$.ajax({
    url: "WebService/ws.aspx/Funcion",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
    destroy: true,
    success: function (result) {}
 });
```

Funciona muy bien pero... al parecer se realiza el llamado a ajax al mismo tiempo, alguna idea de como pausarlos??

Comment: en 2019 se puede usar un array de promesas, cuando todas resuelven se ejecuta una función ( o por cada respuesta de ajax una función y al final cuando todo resolvió otra función ) hay un ejemplo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/188799/81450

Answer (score 0):

Ajax es una tecnología asíncrona, lo que significa que los datos adicionales se solicitan al servidor y se cargan en segundo plano sin interrumpir el comportamiento de la aplicación web. Sin embargo, es posible configurar las peticiones como síncronas de tal forma que la interactividad de la aplicación web se detiene hasta la respuesta por parte del servidor.

En tu caso, estás realizando las llamadas ajax de manera asíncrona(configurada por defecto), lo que significa que se realizan las llamadas y la ejecución continúa sin esperar una respuesta del servidor por cada una de ellas.

Para poder realizar algún proceso por cada respuesta a las llamadas, y así trabajarlas "una después de otra", debes configurar tus llamadas para que se realicen de manera síncrona estableciendo el parámetro **async:false**. Por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "WebService/ws.aspx/Funcion",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async:false
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
    destroy: true,
    success: function (result) {//Proceso por cada respuesta (result) a la llamada//}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizaría recursividad, ya que el uso de **async:false** no está recomendado según la propia documentación de jQuery.

Según tu ejemplo, así quedaría la función **llamadoAjax()**:

```
function llamadoAjax(params, index) {
    // Estoy dando un poco por echo que esta es la estructura de tu array. 
    // Cambiala si fuera necesario
    var parametros = {
        v1: params[index].v1,
        v2: params[index].v2
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "WebService/ws.aspx/Funcion",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
        destroy: true,
        invokedata: { params: params, index: index },
        success: function (result) {
            var 
                params = this.invokedata.params,
                index = this.invokedata.index;

            // Comprueba si hemos llegado al final del array.
            // Si no es asi, usamos recursividad para la siguiente iteración.
            if (params.length < index)
                llamadoAjax(params, index++);
            // Ha llegado al final del array. Finaliza el proceso.
            else
                console.log('Fin del proceso');
        }
     });    
}
```

Y para invocar al proceso, una llamada como cualquier otra. En este caso, el valor inicial de index será 0.

```
llamadoAjax(params, 0);
```