# Recoger en un objeto las respuestas recibidas de 3 URL mediante fetch

Tags: javascript, promesas, fetch

Buenas estoy intentando recopilar en un array los objetos que obtengo de las llamadas fetch() a las 3 url.

```
let log = console.log;
let datafile1 = fetch('http://s3.amazonaws.com/logtrust-static/test/test/data1.json');
let datafile2 = fetch('http://s3.amazonaws.com/logtrust-static/test/test/data2.json');
let datafile3 = fetch('http://s3.amazonaws.com/logtrust-static/test/test/data3.json');
```

Después recibo las promesas de cada llamada y normalizo la información que obtengo

```
   let objeto= {};
        let objetoComb = [];

        let patternDate = /\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*/;
        let categoriePattern = /(CAT)\s\d/;

        datafile1.then (res => res.json())
                 .then(res => res.forEach(re =>{
                     objeto.fecha = re.d;
                     objeto.categoria =re.cat.toUpperCase();
                     //objeto.valor = re.value;
                     objetoComb.push(objeto);

        }));
            objetoComb.push(objeto);

            datafile2.then (res => res.json())
                 .then(res => res.forEach(re =>{
                     objeto.fecha = Date.parse(re.myDate);
                     objeto.categoria =re.categ;
                     objeto.valor = re.val;
                     //log(objeto); 

                     return objetoComb.push(objeto);
        }));

            datafile3.then(res => res.json())
                 .then(res => res.forEach(re =>{
                     //patternDate.test(re.raw);
                     objeto.fecha = Date.parse(re.raw.match(patternDate)[0]);
                     objeto.categoria =re.raw.match(categoriePattern)[0].toString();
                     objeto.valor = re.val;
                     //log(objeto);

                     return objetoComb.push(objeto);
        }));

            log(objetoComb);
```

Pero en log solo me aparece recogido el último elemento de la ultima llamada.

Mi idea era realizar las transformaciones necesarias de la información y agrupar todos los objetos en un mismo array como he dicho antes

Comment: al `log(objetoComb);` tendrías que llamarlo cuando se cumplan todas las promesas, sino va a mostrar datos incompletos, fijate en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/188799/81450 como @amenadiel arma un array de promesas y el log está cuando todas resuelven

Answer (score 1):

puedes tener problemas con ese código debido a que el proceso principal no espera la ejecución de los llamados que haces, y al momento que ejecutas el console.log, puede que obtengas cualquier valor o puedes que no obtengas ninguno. Por ejemplo, si las urls que contienen los archivos json, toman un minuto, no verás nada en la consola.

Te recomiendo que puedas considerar leer mas acerca de las [Promesas en javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

Para el ejemplo que has dado, debes utilizar la función Promise.all para poder esperar a que termine de ejecutarse todas las funciones. Ver [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)

A continuación te presento un ejemplo:

```js
let log = console.log;
let objects = [];
let datafile1 = fetch('http://s3.amazonaws.com/logtrust-static/test/test/data1.json').then(result=>{return result.json();}).then(result=>{objects.push(result)});
let datafile2 = fetch('http://s3.amazonaws.com/logtrust-static/test/test/data2.json').then(result=>{return result.json();}).then(result=>{objects.push(result)});
let datafile3 = fetch('http://s3.amazonaws.com/logtrust-static/test/test/data3.json').then(result=>{return result.json();}).then(result=>{objects.push(result)});

Promise.all([datafile1, datafile2, datafile3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(objects.length);
  console.log(objects);
});
```