# Creo que el servidor me bloquea

Tags: php

Tengo un input donde hago una petición a un servidor externo y recoge los datos solicitados... hasta ahi funciona bien

```
<input name="hash" type="text">
<button class="button button2" type="submit" name="accion" value="Agregar">Agregar


switch ($accion) {
      case "Agregar":
          $contenido  = file_get_contents("paginaweb/$hash");
          $datos      = json_decode($contenido, true);
```

El problema es cuando intento ingresar mas de un dato para ahorrar tiempo (49c9d83acd,8cbe0e9de0,50698a0346,0347d99a61)
Intente hacer un array pero al enviar las peticiones de golpe creo que el servidor me bloquea porque solo devuelve una parte

```
// varias peticiones
       $cadena = '49c9d83acd,8cbe0e9de0,50698a0346,0347d99a61';
       $separar = explode(',', $cadena);
       foreach ($separar as $hash) {
           $contenido  = file_get_contents("paginaweb/$hash");
           $datos      = json_decode($contenido, true);
```

Hay alguna manera de agregar un intervalo de tiempo?

Comment: podes usar un `setTimeout` y un array de promesas, hay un ejemplo por aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188876/81450

Comment: dentro del For siempre estas asignando el contenido al $data. De esa manera se sobreescribe los datos anteriores, y solo te llegara el del ultimo item de la cadena. Te sugiero que cambies de estrategia, o que añadas el $contenido a `$data[]`; de esta manera (con los corchetes) se generara un array en el que cada elemento tendra el contenido de cada item de la cadena.

Answer (score 0):

EN el caso de varias peticiones:

```
   $cadena = '49c9d83acd,8cbe0e9de0,50698a0346,0347d99a61';
   $separar = explode(',', $cadena);
   foreach ($separar as $hash) {
       $contenido  = file_get_contents("paginaweb/$hash");
       $datos      = json_decode($contenido, true);
```

El foreach esta sobrescribiendo encima de $datos con el contenido. De esta manera lo que obtienes al final del bucle es solo los datos del elemento 0347d99a61.

En este caso, puedes añadir cada $contenido en un array, de esta manera;

```
       $datos[]      = json_decode($contenido, true);
```

Con esto, en cada iteracion se crea un elemento dentro del array, con el $contenido decodificado. Luego tendras que tratar ese array en tu proceso (no indicas si quieres guardarlo en bbdd, o mostrarlo por pantalla.)

Comment: Me quede pensando en lo que me decias de cambiar la estrategia usando for, creo que es mas comodo... no se como mostrar el codigo

Comment: ```
   $cadena = "49c9d83acd,8cbe0e9de0,50698a0346,0347d99a61";
   $array  = explode(",", $cadena);
   $count  = count($array);

   for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
       $contenido = file_get_contents("paginaweb/$array[$i]");
       $datos     = json_decode($contenido, true);

       // recojo los datos y  subo a la base de datos
      
   }
```