# Javascript: Promesa pendiente

Tags: javascript

He estado tratando de solucionar este problema pero no lo consigo, cuando intento usar las promesas me dice que está pending promise. He visto que es un problema típico y no consigo arreglarlo... ya que o no dan el ejemplo completo o no lo estoy interpretando bien para arreglarlo... quizá haya más errores, no lo sé.

En mi caso quiero hacer varias peticiones y guardar cada respuesta en una array para después tratar esos datos. Este es el código de la promesa, pero cuando intento usar la función me devuelve la promesa pendiente.

```
var peticiones =  function(url) {                                                
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                                         
        var token = getCookie('_token');                                         
        if (token === '') { //if token cookie is empty, reload page                   
            location.reload();                                                        
        }                                                                             
                                                                                      
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                                           
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {                                    
            const result = this;                                                      
            if (result.readyState === 4){                                             
                if(result.status === 200) {                                           
                    resolve(result.responseText);                                     
                } else {                                                              
                    reject(new Error('¡Ups!'));                                       
                }                                                                     
            }                                                                         
        };                                                                            
                                                                                      
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url);                                                               
        xmlHttp.send();                                                               
    });                                                                               
}   

var procesaPeticiones = async function(urls) {             
      var dataArray = [];                                                                              
      while(urls.length > 0) {                                                                         
          var url = urls.shift();                                                                      
          await peticiones(url)                                                                   
              .then(data => {                                                                          
                  var json = JSON.parse(data);                                                         
                  dataArray.push(json);                                                                
              })
              .then(data => {                                                                          
                 return data;                                                               
              })                                                                        
              .catch(e => {                                                                            
                  console.err(e.message);                                                              
              });                                                                                      
      }                                                                                                
}
```

Otra versión que he probado
``

```
  var dataArray = [];
  while(urls.length > 0) {
      var url = urls.shift();
      await pvetApiMultiple(url)
          .then(data => {
              var json = JSON.parse(data);
              dataArray.push(json);
          })
          .catch(e => {
              console.log(e.message);
          });
  }

  return Promise.all(dataArray).then(data=>{return data;})
```

Comment: Para procesar una lista de Promesas puedes usar [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: y cómo sería? si en lugar del primer .then pongo .all me da error, dice que .all no es una function

Comment: fijate este ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188876/81450 ( el código al final donde dice `  // cuando todas resuelven` )

Comment: He editado la pregunta con la versión con .all que he probado y sigue estando el mismo problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una curiosa mezcla de Javascript "antiguo" y "moderno". Yo usaría async/await sin escribir promesas y usando [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) en lugar de las "arcaicas" llamadas `XmlHttpRequest`:

```javascript
async function peticiones(url) {
  const token = getCookie('_token');
  if (token === '') { //if token cookie is empty, reload page                   
    location.reload();
  }
  return fetch(url).then(data => data.json());
}

async function procesaPeticiones(urls) {
  const dataArray = [];
  while (urls.length > 0) {
    let url = urls.shift();
    dataArray.push(await peticiones(url));
  }
  return dataArray;
}

Promise.all(procesaPeticiones(urls)).then(arrayDeResultados => {
  //...array con todas las respuestas
});
```